# transfer godaddy domain to linode

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, linode

I have a **domain.com** in godaddy.

I have created a new account in linode.

I want use my godaddy **domain.com** in my new account linode.

How can I do it? or Where can I find a guide for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the Linode account set up and know its IP address, configure your domain (and any sub-domains like `www` that you want) to resolve to that IP address in GoDaddy's domain manager.